# apt-get not working after failed attempt to install GUI desktop

Tags: apt, gnome, dpkg

The other day I tried to install GNOME and it didn't complete successfully for some reason. That's fine, I've moved on.

However, everytime I try to use `apt-get` now it ends with a long set of error messages that look to be related to the earlier GNOME installation attempt.

I've tried running `apt-get install -f` and `apt-get autoremove` but they throw the same errors:

```
dpkg: error processing package libgnomeui-0:amd64 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up libgroupsock1 (2014.01.13-1) ... Setting up liblivemedia23 (2014.01.13-1) ... Setting up libmatroska6:amd64 (1.4.1-2+deb8u1) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of avahi-daemon:  avahi-daemon depends on dbus (>= 0.60); however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package avahi-daemon (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnss-mdns:amd64:  libnss-mdns:amd64 depends on avahi-daemon (>= 0.6.16-1); however:   Package avahi-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnss-mdns:amd64 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpam-systemd:amd64:  libpam-systemd:amd64 depends on dbus; however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up libpcrecpp0:amd64 (2:8.35-3.3+deb8u4) ... Setting up libpkcs11-helper1:amd64 (1.11-2) ... Setting up libsdl-image1.2:amd64 (1.2.12-5+b5) ... Setting up libshine3:amd64 (3.1.0-2.1) ... Setting up libtcl8.5:amd64 (8.5.17-1) ... Setting up libtk8.5:amd64 (8.5.17-1) ... Setting up libupnp6 (1:1.6.19+git20141001-1+deb8u1) ... Setting up libusageenvironment1 (2014.01.13-1) ... Setting up libva-drm1:amd64 (1.4.1-1) ... Setting up libva-x11-1:amd64 (1.4.1-1) ... Setting up libvncclient0:amd64 (0.9.9+dfsg2-6.1+deb8u2) ... Setting up libxcb-composite0:amd64 (1.10-3+b1) ... Setting up opensc-pkcs11:amd64 (0.14.0-2) ... Setting up openssh-client (1:6.7p1-5+deb8u3) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of accountsservice:  accountsservice depends on dbus; however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package accountsservice (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aisleriot:  aisleriot depends on gconf2 (>=
2.28.1-2); however:   Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package aisleriot (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up autotools-dev (20140911.1) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of policykit-1:  policykit-1 depends on libpam-systemd; however:   Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.  policykit-1 depends on dbus; however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package policykit-1 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-system-log:  gnome-system-log depends on policykit-1; however:   Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-system-log (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tracker:  tracker depends on dbus (>= 1.3.1); however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tracker (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tracker-gui:  tracker-gui depends on tracker (=
1.2.4-2); however:   Package tracker is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tracker-gui (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bijiben:  bijiben depends on tracker; however:   Package tracker is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bijiben (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluez:  bluez depends on dbus; however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udisks2:  udisks2 depends on dbus; however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.  udisks2 depends on libpam-systemd; however:   Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs-daemons:  gvfs-daemons depends on udisks2; however:   Package udisks2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs-daemons (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox:  rhythmbox depends on dbus; however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugins:  rhythmbox-plugins depends on rhythmbox (= 3.1-1); however:   Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugins (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder:  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder depends on rhythmbox (= 3.1-1); however:   Package rhythmbox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gvfs:amd64:  gvfs:amd64 depends on gvfs-daemons (>= 1.22.2-1); however:   Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.  gvfs:amd64 depends on gvfs-daemons (<<
1.22.2-1.1~); however:   Package gvfs-daemons is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gvfs:amd64 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus:  nautilus depends on gvfs (>= 1.3.2); however:   Package gvfs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brasero:  brasero depends on gvfs; however:   Package gvfs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package brasero (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up cdbs (0.4.130+deb8u1) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of colord:  colord depends on policykit-1 (>= 0.103); however:   Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package colord (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of empathy:  empathy depends on dbus-x11; however:   Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package empathy (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of evolution-plugins:  evolution-plugins depends on evolution (= 3.12.9~git20141130.241663-1+b1); however:   Package evolution is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package evolution-plugins (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up fonts-freefont-ttf (20120503-4) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-settings-daemon:  gnome-settings-daemon depends on libpam-systemd; however:   Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-settings-daemon (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-media:  gnome-media depends on gstreamer0.10-gconf; however:   Package gstreamer0.10-gconf:amd64 is not configured yet.  gnome-media depends on gstreamer0.10-plugins-good; however:   Package gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-media (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-bluetooth:  gnome-bluetooth depends on bluez (>= 5.5); however:   Package bluez is not configured yet.  gnome-bluetooth depends on libpam-systemd; however:   Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-bluetooth (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:  gnome-shell depends on evolution-data-server (>= 3.7.90); however:   Package evolution-data-server is not configured yet.  gnome-shell depends on gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.4.0); however:   Package gnome-settings-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of upower:  upower depends on dbus; however:   Package dbus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package upower (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-session-bin:  gnome-session-bin depends on dbus-x11; however:   Package dbus-x11 is not configured yet.  gnome-session-bin depends on upower (>= 0.9.0); however:   Package upower is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-session-bin (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-session:  gnome-session depends on gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.0); however:   Package gnome-settings-daemon is not configured yet.  gnome-session depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.0); however:   Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.  gnome-session depends on gnome-session-bin (>= 3.14.0-2); however:   Package gnome-session-bin is not configured yet.  gnome-session depends on gnome-session-bin (<< 3.15); however:   Package gnome-session-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-session (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:  gdm3 depends on libpam-systemd; however:   Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.  gdm3 depends on gnome-session-bin (>= 3.10); however:   Package gnome-session-bin is not configured yet.  gdm3 depends on gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.2); however:   Package gnome-settings-daemon is not configured yet.  gdm3 depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.10.1-2~); however:   Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.  gdm3 depends on accountsservice (>= 0.6.12); however: Package accountsservice is not configured yet.  gdm3 depends on policykit-1 (>= 0.105-5~); however:   Package policykit-1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-control-center:  gnome-control-center depends on accountsservice; however:   Package accountsservice is not configured yet.  gnome-control-center depends on colord (>= 0.1.30); however:   Package colord is not configured yet.  gnome-control-center depends on gnome-settings-daemon (>= 3.13.91); however:   Package gnome-settings-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-control-center (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Setting up libgfortran-4.9-dev:amd64 (4.9.2-10) ... Setting up gfortran-4.9 (4.9.2-10) ... Setting up gfortran (4:4.9.2-2) ... update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gfortran to provide /usr/bin/f95 (f95) in auto mode update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gfortran to provide /usr/bin/f77 (f77) in auto mode dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-contacts:  gnome-contacts depends on libfolks-eds25 (>= 0.7.3); however:   Package libfolks-eds25:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-contacts (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: too many errors, stopping Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u1) ... Errors were encountered while processing:  dbus  dbus-x11  gcr  gnome-keyring evolution-data-server  evolution  gconf2  libgnomevfs2-common  libgnomevfs2-0:amd64  libgnome2-common  libgnome-2-0:amd64  libgnome2-bin  libgnome2-0:amd64  libbonoboui2-0:amd64  gstreamer0.10-gconf:amd64  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64  libfarstream-0.1-0:amd64  libfolks-eds25:amd64  libgnomeui-0:amd64  avahi-daemon  libnss-mdns:amd64  libpam-systemd:amd64  accountsservice aisleriot  policykit-1  gnome-system-log  tracker  tracker-gui  bijiben  bluez  udisks2  gvfs-daemons  rhythmbox  rhythmbox-plugins  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder  gvfs:amd64  nautilus  brasero  colord  empathy  evolution-plugins  gnome-settings-daemon  gnome-media  gnome-bluetooth  gnome-shell  upower  gnome-session-bin  gnome-session gdm3  gnome-control-center  gnome-contacts Processing was halted because there were too many errors. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) root@hack-r:~# screen  udisks2  gvfs-daemons  rhythmbox  rhythmbox-plugins  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder  gvfs:amd64  nautilus  brasero  colord  empathy  evolution-plugins  gnome-settings-daemon  gnome-media  gnome-bluetooth  gnome-shell  upower  gnome-session-bin  gnome-session gdm3  gnome-control-center  gnome-contacts Processing was halted because there were too many errors. E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and a bunch more like that then

```
 udisks2
 gvfs-daemons
 rhythmbox
 rhythmbox-plugins
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
 gvfs:amd64
 nautilus
 brasero
 colord
 empathy
 evolution-plugins
 gnome-settings-daemon
 gnome-media
 gnome-bluetooth
 gnome-shell
 upower
 gnome-session-bin
 gnome-session
 gdm3
 gnome-control-center
 gnome-contacts
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: *How* did you try to install GNOME desktop? Posting the exact steps and where it failed, error messages, etc. may lead to a solution.

Comment: @MichaelBay It's a good and fair question, but I was following a tutorial and didn't record that info. I believe it was just apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment and some dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

for keeping your Packages up-to-date. Try

```
apt-get purge gnome
```

for deleting the package with all attached files to it. Also repeated the last step for any further broken packages mentioned in the error messages.

Comment: dpkg: error processing package task-gnome-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
 gnome-bluetooth
 gnome-user-share
 gnome-core
 task-gnome-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@hack-r:~#

Comment: Also try apt-get dist-upgrade, I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Actually `apt-get purge` worked thanks!!! The trick was I had to run it for each item on that list in my comment. I will accept your answer.